# Xcode UI Testing Failure - Computed invalid hit point

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode-ui-testing, xcode8

My Xcode UI testcode is failing with this error, when the test runs on iPad Pro 12.9 inch. For all iPhone model and for iPad Retina, there is no error seen.

> Assertion Failure: EasyTVUITests.m:81: UI Testing Failure - Computed
>   invalid hit point (-1.0, -1.3) for Cell 0x600000377dc0: traits:
>   8589934592, {{411.0, -1373.0}, {813.3, 106.3}}

The failing test code line is this one:

```
[[app.tables[@"programs"].cells elementBoundByIndex:17] tap];
```

**What does the error actually mean, and how do I debug it?**

Here is the full run up to the error:

> Tap Cell
>
> ```
> Wait for app to idle
>
> Find the Cell
>
>    Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.[hidden]
>
>    Find: Descendants matching type Table
>
>    Find: Elements matching predicate '"programs" IN identifiers'
>
>    Find: Descendants matching type Cell
>
>    Find: Element at index 17
>
>    Wait for app to idle
>
> Synthesise event
>
>    Assertion Failure: EasyTVUITests.m:81: UI Testing Failure - Computed invalid hit point (-1.0, -1.3) for Cell 0x600000377dc0: traits: 8589934592, {{411.0, -1373.0}, {813.3, 106.3}}
> ```

That the index is 17 is not important - I am just trying to pick a random cell. I tried another index, but it did not make any difference.

Visually the iPad Pro version does not look "wrong" or different from the iPad retina version.

This is Xcode 8.1 and the iPad simulator runs iOS 10.1.

Comment: If anyone arrives here because `app.buttons["delete"].tap()` isn't working (like I did), you can swap it for `element.typeText(XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete)` where `element` is the text field or similar that you want the delete key to be sent to.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue on iPad Pro (12.9 inch), while my code was running smoothly on iPad Retina.

Do you use the `XCUIElement's isHittable` test somewhere before the failing line?
Because for some reason, in my code, running this test on the iPad Pro (12.9 inch) returns `YES` while on all other simulators it returns `NO`.

I found it comparing the console outputs of runs on different simulators.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the very same issue. By using the force tap I fixed the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011697/2430555

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that you are trying to execute a tap at a coordinate that is not valid. In this case, (-1.0, -1.3), which is to the left and above the top left corner of the screen.

The position of the cell it is trying to hit appears to be valid - its x coordinate is positive and its y coordinate is negative, indicating that the cell you want is above the screen in a vertically scrollable view. If this is the case and you can verify that the 17th cell can be tapped manually, I think you should file a bug with Apple at [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 2):

I also have had this kind of issue, an invalid hit point, but for an element which was displayed on screen, so not a scroll issue.

I managed to fix it for iPad Retina and iPad Pro 9.7 inch using the force tap method described on this page http://samwize.com/2016/02/28/everything-about-xcode-ui-testing-snapshot/

But it wasn't working on iPad Pro 12.9inch because the isHittable property was true on it.

In the end the problem was I was trying to tap an element on the main view while a popover was displayed, so while it was in reality hittable, xcuitests assumed it wasn't. I now perform a dummy forceTap actions to force dismiss the popover before performing the tap action that used to be failing. Works well on all three kind of iPads.

Comment: I know my answer isn't a direct response to the question, but I think it might help some people with invalid hit point issues.